# How do select data with IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I get data from MySQL with `if` statement as code below. but I get an error: 
`Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)`.

so can someone can help me?

I can not put it into the procedure, because I am using spring + mybatis in the project and i will put this code into them.

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE someField = 'A') < 0,
        (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE someField = 'A'),
        (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE someField = 'A'))
```

Comment: Simply `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE someField = 'A'`. It is impossible when `COUNT(*)` returns negative result.

Comment: Does `table1` and `table2` structures are fully the same?

Comment: 'I wanna get data from MySQL with if statement as code below' - that's not a goer ,what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Akina no, two tables has a little difference

Comment: If so you must use stored procedure. Or synchronize the structures by adding literal (empty?) fields until structures matched fully.

Comment: @Akina I can't do that. cuz Table 1 has less field than table 2. i think i must resolve it by java code .

Comment: Build a stored procedure for this like @Akina suggested If can't return more than 1 element

Comment: I won't be providing an answer because I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them. But for (potential) further help (from others) see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry tks, I have updated my question. this is first time i post  a question, so i  don't know the rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: *I wanna get data of 1 in 2 tables when table 1 don't have data I will get data from table 2*.

That sounds like `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select * from table1 where someField = 'A'
union all
select * from table2 where not exists(select 1 from tabe1 where someField = 'A'
```

Note that, for this to work, both tables *must* contain exactly the same number of columns, whith aligned datatypes. You should really be enumerating the columns that you want to show in the resultset in both `unioned` queries, to avoid any possible ambiguity. If needed, you can `cast` columns or add litteral values to any or both of the resultset to align the resultsets (without seeing your actual data structures, I cannot tell how to do).

Comment: thank so much, Although not the same as what I need but with this way, I have made it work